# Plugin development: is adding empty index.php files necessary?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, security

When developing a plugin, should I includes the blank `index.php` file and then add my functions in the `plugin-name.php`? Or is that unnecessary? What file structure is recommended?

**This?**

```
/some-plugin/some-plugin.php (functions)
/some-plugin/index.php (blank)
```

**Or this?**

```
/some-plugin/index.php (functions)
```

From doing some research on WPSE, I have found a Q&A related to my own question:

- [**Should Plugin Folders Include a Blank index.php File?** - WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45365)

However, this question is over four years ago and I wanted to know if this is still a recommendation for ethical plugin development nowadays.

The answers that were given by [Wyck](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45369/98212) and [toscho](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45366/98212) bring up interesting points on both sides of the spectrum:

1. **For**: *security through obscurity works, bots compile the plugin lists right off WordPress.org and crawl the plugin's URL directly*
2. **Against**: *unused PHP files in that directory are wasting time and memory when WordPress is searching for plugins*

Are these two statements true? What's the latest update?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is an exact duplicate. _Are the answers to X still valid?_, is not a good question here, because it would result in many, many duplicates.

Comment: @toscho On questions that are dated, how do we check if the answers still apply to the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: By testing it against the latest release. If there are no new issues, no need to re-ask. Otherwise, add a bounty to the existing question, asking for new answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good practice to include `index.php`, with and without a wordpress context. Appach 2.4+ IIRC will add a log message about a missing file if someone access the directory itself, which makes reading the error log more annoying.

As for the reason you quote, obviously this do not have any security related impact, and the "wordpress will have to parse one more file once a year".... you are a great developer if that is the only performance issue you have in your code, and with php 5.6 code caching even that claim might not be true any longer.

You can put your code in the `index.php` file but by now people have expectations about the naming of the "main" plugin file, and therefor it might create pointless confusion as most people will assume `index.php` is an empty file

Comment: When you say _confusion_ are you referring to when people want to run a function to check if a plugin is activated by using `is_plugin_active( 'some-plugin/some-plugin.php' )` because that is the expected format? From what I understand with your answer, adding at an `index.php` prevents unnecessary logging of a false error from Apache and using 'some-plugin/some-plugin.php' is a widely accepted practice in plugin development?

Comment: yes, you got it right. The confusion is from it being the widely accepted practice. People that do not pay attention to details like file size might assume for a moment that there are some files missing if you include your main code in `index.php`